# Not Receiving Growl Messages from Autotest on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest, growl

I am following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org) . In Chapter 3, the author covers testing. Everything seems to be working according to the instructions, but I don't get Growl notifications (green or red) after starting autotest. Also, in Growl, it says "No Applications Have Registered Yet".

**References:**

- I tried both gem installs mentioned
  in the [autotest-growl](https://github.com/svoop/autotest-growl) readme
- I blindly loaded the gem
  karl-autotest-growl, although the [blog describing it](http://monket.net/blog/2009/07/autotest-growl-for-windows/), although clearly written, is a bit dated
- ph7spot has a fairly [detailed walkthough][4] to setup autotest for linux, windows, and xos (http://ph7spot.com/musings/getting-started-with-autotest)

**My setup:**

- Windows 7 64bit
- Growl v2.0.6 (build
  2.0.6.1)

**c:\Sites.autotest file contents:**

```
    require 'autotest/growl'
    require 'autotest/fsevent'
    require 'redgreen/autotest'
    require "test_notifier/autotest"
```

**gemfile contents:**

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
    gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'

    group :development do
      gem 'rspec-rails', '2.5.0'
    end

    group :test do
      gem 'rspec', '2.5.0'
      gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
      gem 'win32-process'
      gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc5'
    end
```

**"gemfile list" output: (partial)**

```
autotest (4.4.6)
autotest-growl (0.2.9)
autotest-rails (4.1.0)
autotest-rails-pure (4.1.2)
autotest-standalone (4.5.5)
karl-autotest-growl (0.1.8)
rails (3.0.7)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rspec (2.5.0)
rspec-core (2.5.2)
rspec-expectations (2.5.0)
rspec-mocks (2.5.0)
rspec-rails (2.5.0)
spork (0.9.0.rc5)
webrat (0.7.1)
ZenTest (4.5.0)
```

Please let me know if you have any questions or suggestions on how I could troubleshoot the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .autotest file path is not correct. It should be:

```
C:\sites\sample_app\.autotest
```

Also you need to remove the `require 'autotest/fsevent'` line from the .autotest file as it is for OSX only.

Comment: Thank you. autotest now registers with Growl. I think I have a separate issue keeping the tests from running. Now I will work on that. Thanks again!