# Ruby Autotest on Windows and Growl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, autotest, growl

I'm working through Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial for Rails 3, and there's a few things I'm trying to get setup, and I'm a bit stumped.  First, autotest seems to run fine in and of itself.  It does seem to take a bit longer than anything I've seen as to run two tests it's taking over seven seconds, but it works.  However, I'm trying to get it to give Growl notifications.  I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372370/not-receiving-growl-messages-from-autotest-on-windows) and I'm a bit lost by the answer.  The answer advises to modify the .autotest file in the working directory, in this case sample_app.  However, I don't have any .autotest files in that directory.  The only ones I seem to have are in other gems in the main Ruby directory in the gem libraries.  Also, I'm unfamiliar with his Gemlist file as I've got a Gemlist.Lock file that looks similar in that directory, but it has no references to autotest.  The actual Gemfile he posted is the same, but he does have Spork and the Win32 Process which I don't seem to have.

So if I'm supposed to have an .autotest file in my sample_app directory, how do I get one there?  And why doesn't it seem to be in my Gemlist.lock file?

If needed, here's the output from when I run autotest:

```
C:\Ruby193\work\rails_tutorial\sample_app>autotest
loading autotest/rails_rspec2
C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby -rrubygems -S 'C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/exe/rspec' --tty 'C:/Ruby193/work/rails_tutorial/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb'
```

..

```
Finished in 8.57 seconds
2 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 6674
```

Any suggestions/assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled getting Growl to work in Windows as well. It looks as if you're using MRI via RubyInstaller, where I used JRuby, but maybe my writeup will help.

http://journeymandev.com/2012/7/28/rails-growl-and-windows

Comment: I'll have to check that out when I get home.  Read through it and you mention that I need to change the .autotest file in the root of the project.  That's my base question.  I don't have any .autotest files except that exist as parts of other gems.  So do I create one, and if so, what do I put in it.  If I don't create it, then what is supposed to create it so I can modify it?

Comment: You create the `.autotest` file in your project's root directory. Then put `reqiure 'autotest/growl'` as the first line in that file.

Comment: Awesome!  Ok, everything I've seen has said to put that in there, but not to create the actual file.  So I thought I had something wrong.  I'll try this out tonight.  Thank you so much Nathan!